# Laravel / Livewire: Ignore "image" rule when updating

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload, laravel-livewire

Simply put, i have to update the user.

This is my validation rule for the image:

```
protected $rules = [
    //other rules
    "profile_image" => "sometimes|image|max:1024",
];
```

Mount method:

```
public function mount($user)
{
    //other
    $this->profile_image = $user->profile_image;
}
```

The validation rules work as expected, but the problem is i store the image into the database as a string: example of how it looks `profile_image: "public/images/tprYt36hk0Ztun9yKBYpUGEX3TJuAaBWMi5bSkTZ.jpg"`

This means that when i want to update the user without changing the profile image, i can't because of the `image` validation rule, i can only pass when an image is selected.

This is how my update method looks:

```
public function updateCook()
{
    $this->validate();
    try {

        $image = $this->profile_image->store("public/images");

        $this->user->update([
            //other updates
            "profile_image" => $image,
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'User is updated');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        session()->flash('error', 'An error occured');
    }
}
```

If i remove the `image` validation rule and try submitting the form without uploading a new image i get **Call to a member function store() on string**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer:

```
protected $rules = [
    "profile_image" => "nullable|image|max:1024",
];
```

Then as @Khan Tran said i simply removed `$this->profile_image = $user->profile_image;` in the `mount()` method

In my `updateCook()` method i did this:

```
public function updateCook()
{
    $this->validate();
    try {
        if ($this->profile_image) {
            $image = $this->profile_image->store("public/images");
            $this->user->update([
                // + other updates
                "profile_image" => $image,
                
            ]);
        } else {
            // No new image is uploaded, update other fields only
            $this->user->update([
                //Oter updates
            ]);
        }

        session()->flash('success', 'User is updated');      

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        session()->flash('error', 'Грешка при ажурирањето на корисникот.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are assigning $this->profile_image = $this->user->profile_image. You shouldn't do that because they have different types

```
public function mount($user)
{
    //other
    //$this->profile_image = $user->profile_image;
}
```

If you want show image in view, use $this->user->profile_image instead

For $rules:

```
protected $rules = [
    //other rules
    "profile_image" => "nullable|image|max:1024",
];
```

Within updateCook() method:

```
//...
if ($this->profile_image) {
    $image = $this->profile_image->store("public/images");
    $this->user->update([
       //other updates
       "profile_image" => $image,
    ]);

   session()->flash('success', 'User is updated');
}
//..
```

.

Comment: Yes i do have it assigned like this: $this->profile_image = $user->profile_image; But what do you mean by separating them ?

Comment: I mean don't assign $this->profile_image = $user->profile_image;

Comment: Still doesn't pass without adding an image. If i add the updateCook() method is called

Comment: Can you show new code and your blade view?

Comment: I've posted the answer